# MySQL multiple joins - how do i display the data? (using PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, join

Ok, i know this is stupid but I'm stuck and I need a kick in the head.
I have 3 tables (orders, orderitems, products) and I'm using 2 left outer joins in a query to display the orders history in the clients section:

```
SELECT * FROM orderitems oi, orders o
LEFT OUTER JOIN product p ON p.dbarcode = oi.orderitems_item
WHERE o.order_code = oi.orderitems_ordercode 
    AND oi.orderitems_ordercode = '".$_GET['ordercode']."'`
```

I can display a row for each product in the table order_items but I can't seem to display (echo) the total amount which is held in the field orders.order_amount, i presume it has to do with the fact that the field has multiple instances or whatsoever. How do I display data as a result of several tables joined?

Edit for Quassnoi:

I loop through the results and create a table row for each one and, after the loop, i want to display the general total:

```
  <? do { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><? echo $row_OrderItems['dbarcode']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row_OrderItems['name']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row_OrderItems['orderitems_quantity']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row_OrderItems['price']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <? } while ($row_OrderItems = mysql_fetch_assoc($OrderItems)); ?>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">Total order amount (incl. shipping and handling): &euro; <? echo $row_OrderItems['order_amounteuro']; ?></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Would adding `o.order_amount AS order_amount` in the SELECT help?

Comment: you need to store the total before the while loop ends.

Comment: Yes, I've realised that the reason I cant display the total is because it's outside the loop, however i need to display it there and not inside the repeated region. Any ideas?

Comment: see my answer below, i updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<? do { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><? echo $row_OrderItems['dbarcode']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row_OrderItems['name']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row_OrderItems['orderitems_quantity']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row_OrderItems['price']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <? 
$total = $row_OrderItems['order_amounteuro']; // store the total, before you loop past the last row
} while ($row_OrderItems = mysql_fetch_assoc($OrderItems)); ?>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">Total order amount (incl. shipping and handling): &euro; <? echo $total; ?></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Yes, I have, i'm using print_r and I can see all the data correctly.

Answer (score 3):

`o.order_amount` will be repeated in every row, just take the first one.

And, of course, never use this:

```
oi.orderitems_ordercode = '".$_GET['ordercode']."'`
```

without `mysql_real_escape_string`.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I do sanitize the inputs, I just used the above as an example! I loved the cartoon strip though! :)

Comment: Forgot to ask though, HOW do I display only the first instance? If i simply echo out the field ie echo $row_orderinfo('order_amout') it shows nothing although the data has been fetched (i can see it with print_r)

Comment: @bikey77: please post a sample of your code (as an update to your original post)

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI, this part of your statement:

```
SELECT * FROM orderitems oi, orders o 
LEFT OUTER JOIN product p ON p.dbarcode = oi.orderitems_item
```

is fetching everything from `orderitems`, `orders` and `products`. Prefix the `*` with the table you want all the fields from, or rewrite it to fetch specific fields.

Comment: I get your point but doesnt the condition "AND oi.orderitems_ordercode = '".$_GET['ordercode']."'" do the job and just pull the specific records from the database?